# Cross-subdomain tracking with multiple Google Analytics accounts.

Tags: google-analytics

I administer a university website which we'll say is at www.university.edu. The colleges within the university each have their own website on a subdomain such as law.university.edu and business.university.edu.

Each college has their own Google Analytics account and code snippet installed on their site. So for example Law has UA-XXXXX1-1 on their site and Business has UA-XXXXX2-1 on their site. Each of these profiles only track usage on their particular subdomain.

As the main site owner, it is in our interest to track usage across www.university.edu as well as every college subdomain site within a single Google Analytics profile separate from the college's GA account, say UA-XXXXX0-1. Each of the colleges uses a common footer which allows me to add my tracking snippet to every page on the domain.

How do I format my tracking snippet so that I can track visitors across the subdomains, but also so that the colleges don't have to update their snippets and our data doesn't conflict with each others?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know there are two approaches to cross-domain tracking.

First one is the way you do: install different tracking codes and handle different GA accounts. This is not very flexible and you've already faced one the issues it can produce. From what i see, there's only one way to achieve your goal without modifying tracking scripts: create a new GA account and grant access to it from all other accounts ([here's the HowTo](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55500)).

Second approach is much more preferrable, but in your case it would require modifying tracking codes and i guess it would cause your current data loss. Withing that approach a single tracking code is used for every subdomain ([Video tutorial](http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/domains_subdomains/index.html)). Cross-domain data conflicts are handled by proper profiling with filters.